# No information: drawing cards from a well shuffled deck

Tags: probability

What is meant by "it is as if the first card had never been drawn!" in the problem below?

And also "You learned nothing from the first draw so it has no effect on your estimate of the outcome of the second draw."?

When I approached the problem myself, I didn't even think about the case where an ace of spades was drawn the first time. I've seen a number of problems like this but nothing implicit like this was ever explained. Can anyone elaborate?

[image]

Comment: I think the explanation in the text is pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

Case 1: Someone flips the top card and you get to look at it and you see it is in fact the ace of spades.  The person then asks you whether you think the second card from the deck is an ace of spades.  You, being the savvy card player you are, know that there is only one ace of spades in the entire deck, so since you can see it in front of you face up, you know that the second card cannot possibly be it.  The probability is then zero.

Case 2: Someone flips the top card and you get to look at it and you see that it is *not* the ace of spades.  The person then asks you whether you think the second card from the deck is an ace of spades.  You, being the savvy card player you are, know that there is one ace of spades left somewhere in the deck and only 51 cards left in the deck, so the probability is $\frac{1}{51}$.

---

Compare this to the following:

Case 3: Someone removes the top card of the deck without showing you what it was.  He then asks you what the probability is of the next card in the deck being an ace of spades.

Case 4: Someone removes the top card of the deck without showing you what it was.  He then pulls what was the second card and places it face down on the table and then puts the original top card back on top of the deck.  He then asks you what the probability is of the face down card in front of you being the ace of spades.

Case 5: Someone asks you what the probability is of the top card of the deck being the ace of spades.

It should be clear that cases 3,4, and 5 all have the same probability.

---

What they mean by "it is as if the first card was never drawn in the first place" is saying that that the case 5 that I wrote above has the same probability as case 3 (the original wording of the problem).  However, if you had the opportunity to see what the top card actually was, then you will be in cases 1 or 2 and given your current knowledge will have additional information and can make a more accurate assumption about the probability.

Comment: I see now. We aren't provided any new information to update the probability. Thus the name "No Information". Do you know of any examples similar to this? Either simple problems or examples in the real world.

Comment: @Anon Expanding on this example, we could think of our sample space as all $52!$ different ways of shuffling the cards.  Rewording the question as "dealing all cards in a line face down, what is the probability that the second card is ace of spades?", in a similar fashion, we don't actually care about the third through fifty-second card.

Comment: @Anon An unrelated question: "Your friend wants to meet you for lunch but he forgot to tell you where to meet.  You know he only eats at three places (with equal probability).  You also know that he doesn't eat at the same place two days in a row, but you don't know where he ate yesterday or the days before.  What is the probability that if you guess where to go to meet him that you are correct?"  Here, the fact that he ate somewhere yesterday doesn't give us any information about which restaurant he is likely to be at.

Answer (score 0):

It uses [the law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Namely, let $X_1,X_2$ be values of the first and the second card, respectively. Then

$$P\{X_2=\text{}\}=P\{X_2=\text{}\mid X_1=\text{}\}P\{X_1=\text{}\}+P\{X_2=\text{}\mid X_1\ne\text{}\}P\{X_1\ne\text{}\}$$ 
$$=0\times\frac{1}{52}+\frac{1}{51}\times\frac{51}{52}=\frac{1}{52}$$